# Trying to download HTML content of div with a JS function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm creating an email template generator form, and am trying to find a way to copy the HTML contents of the div being generated either to a clipboard or to a new HTML file to be able to easily paste it into an email client.

I'm using this function right now:

```
function download() {
   $('<a />').attr({
      download: 'export.html', 
      href: "data:text/html," + "<html><body>" + $('#exportthis').html() + "</body></html>"
   })[0].click()
};
```

It does save the new HTML file, though it's only copying about half of the first line of code of the div. Seems like it's getting stuck somewhere along the way. I'm having trouble understanding why.

Any ideas here?

Comment: Since `data:` is a URL, you’d need to worry about URL encoding. Why not use the [`Blob` API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) instead?

Comment: @SebastianSimon I'm not familiar with the Blob API, to be honest with you. I'll take a look into it now. Thanks!